# Cut a cake with minimal exposed area

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

Take a typical round (cylindrical) cake and cut a chunk out. Return the next day to do the same... repeat...

Cakes dry out primarily at their exposed surface. So ideally, one would want to cut the cake so that at any given time the total exposed area is minimized.

For the first cut, a (nearly) semi-circular cut seems best, as that gives the minimum surface for removed volume. But the second cut would be to enlarge the existing cut by removing a C-shaped piece. But that doesn't work all the way, once you get about half way it seems the cut should be straight across.

My feeling is that you cut increasingly straight curves until half the cake is gone, and then increasingly curved again past that.

Is there an obvious algo here?

Comment: How much is a chunk? Why don't you eat it all?

Comment: Chunk size is anything less than half the cake (otherwise you'd cut down the middle and be done). I don't eat it all because I have Type 2.

Comment: I find the problem interesting, hence the upvote. But I think the problem is still not well-defined: do we assume that each chunk is very small compared to the total, or they can be of any size (even almost half of the cake)? If we cut several chunks, then  are all the chunks of the same size? And do we want to minimize the surface at each step (i.e. every cut minimizes its own surface area), or do we want to minimize an overall exposure to air (i.e. something like the sum of exposed surface areas after every cut)?

Comment: Let's say each chunk is any value less than 1/5th of the cake, just so we force the problem to be multi-cut. As to the second question, the second - we're trying to stop the cake drying out so we want to minimize the exposed area of the remaining cake. I suspect there's no sum, as I FEEL that a single section being enlarged will result in the minimum surface, but maybe not.

Comment: I see that you allow curved cuts. Are cuts that leave the remaining cake spherical permitted?

Comment: @AngelaRichardson - ahhh. Hmm, I would say no, we're talking "normal" cuts here (for both definitions of that word).

Comment: Does the cut have to go from top to bottom? If not, can't you just take a very small slice off the top without it letting it go to the bottom? Also, do you want to maximize volume cut while minimizing surface area of the leftover cake?

Comment: @Hiten - yes, cut through. Like real people cutting a cake. I assume yes to the second, but I'm curious why you might ask? And note it's only the INTERNAL surface area, the outer surface has icing and doesn't dry out.

Comment: Hmm, then can you do something like this? Find an equation of the hyperplane that should divide the cake (y=f(x) for some f). We can find the intersection of the hyperplane and cake given f. Use this to find the area and the volume of the cut cake?